# Break outside of two loops

Tags: python, while-loop, break

I'm writing a code with a while loop inside a while loop and am wondering how to break out of the outer loop if I meet the necessary conditions in the inner loop.

```
while N <= 8:
    while i < 60:
        if this:
            that
        elif this:
            that other thing
        else:
            break
        i += 1
    if while loop has found the right thing:
        N += 1
    else:
        change conditions
```

This break command will only break out of the first loop, so I'm wondering how to simply break out both. It might be worth mentioning that all this is in another `for` loop which I wouldn't want to break out of. Thank you.

Comment: Set a variable that is checked after the inner loop?

Comment: Raise an exception and put the  top while loop in a try/except block?

Comment: `break` only breaks out of the smallest enclosing loop. At which postion in your code do you want to break from the outer loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `flag`:

```
flag = True
while N <= 8:
    while i < 60:
        if this:
            that
        elif this:
            that other thing
        else:
            flag = False    # To exit from outer while loop
            break
        i += 1
    if(not flag):               
        break               # Condition in inner loop is met
    if while loop has found the right thing:
        N += 1
    else:
        change conditions
```

Comment: Check if `true / false` or `True / False` in Python

Comment: @DineshPanchananam I was trying to explain the `concept of flags` which is not specific to a language. Anyway thanks for mentioning I will correct it.

Comment: After the `break` of inner loop, flag is False, which is never run the break of outter loop. I think the second condition is `if not flag`. Anw, your idea is good

Answer (score 6):

Encapsulate it in a function and return when you are done?

Answer (score 2):

Use a flag; `trigger` is used here

```
trigger = False
while N <= 8:
    while i < 60:
        if this:
            that
        elif this:
            that other thing
        else:
            trigger = True
            break
        i += 1
    if trigger:
        break
    elif while loop has found the right thing:
        N += 1
    else:
        change conditions
```